# SQLite in memory linked to .NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, frameworks, entity

I have an existing (encrypted) SQLite DB and I want to dynamically decrypt and load it into memory. Does anyone know how I can tell the c# .NET Entity Framework to use my "in memory"-DB?!

Maybe there's an option @ App.Config?! I don't want my database lying around decrypted on HDD.

Regards,
DoubleVoid

Edit:
I want to load the whole SQLite DB into memory (e.G.: a variable, byte-stream...) and tell EF to communicate with this object/stream.
I don't want to have a connectionstring in my App.Config like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EF.Model1.csdl|res://*/EF.Model1.ssdl|res://*/EF.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=EF\Chinook_Sqlite_AutoIncrementPKs.sqlite&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When you load the `Entity Container` it is `In-Memory`.

Comment: It makes calls to your DB.

Comment: Normally, I tell the EF in the connection string where to find my SQLlite DB. But I first want to load it into memory (variable) and then "attach" it to the EF...so there is no ConnectionsString in the App.config

Comment: Sure, there is an overload for the `Entity Model` where you supply the connection string with the initialization of the `Entity Model`.

Comment: @DonA: Okay, but the connection string has to point to a file on the local HDD, right?! I want to point to an object in memory instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload for the Entity Model where you supply the connection string with the initialization of the Entity Model.

```
var model = new yourModel(ModelConnStr());
```

Helper function:

```
public static string ModelConnStr()
{
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlcon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlcon.DataSource = "your datasource";
sqlcon.InitialCatalog = "your db";
sqlcon.UserID = "id";
sqlcon.Password = "pswrd";
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder mdlcon = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
mdlcon.Metadata = "res://*/BMModel.csdl|res://*/BMModel.ssdl|res://*/BMModel.msl";
mdlcon.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
mdlcon.ProviderConnectionString = sqlcon.ConnectionString;
return mdlcon.ConnectionString;
}
```

Now with sqLite you may to use a diff but similar object.

Comment: I repeat myself here :): Okay, but the connection string has to point to a file on the local HDD, right?! I want to point to an object in memory instead.

Comment: Okay, I don't get what I would put @ DataSource?! I read the DB into memory with a binary stream or something, I have the whole DB in memory now (decrypted)...(the SQLlite DB is still encrypted on the HDD)...how do I tell EF to use my memory object to be the data source?! ... i want to make all the db changes in memory, and when the programm closes write it back to hdd (encrypted)

Comment: Location of your server

Comment: If you wrote the connection string out what would you put for the `datasource=` part?

Comment: ATM it would be .: "databases\mydatabase.sqlite". this points to a file on my disk. I read something about putting this: ":memory:" ... but I don't know where I tell EF to load the DB from a variable/memory.